# Rails app, get different URL's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, model, routes, gallery

I am rebuilding my websites photo gallery and want a different URL scheme for each part and i'm just a bit unsure how to go about it.

I need to get the structure of my models etc.

The gallery consists of 4 models:

- Collection
- Album
- Photo
- PhotoSize

a Collection can contain other collections or albums but NOT both at the same time.

I wish the main url to the gallery to be /gallery rather than the current /collections

So as a user navigates deeper in the gallery I wish the URL to become something along the lines of:

/gallery/collections/collection1name/albums/album1name/photos/photo1name

if a user is only 1 photo, 1 album and 1 collection deep and...

/gallery/collections/collection1name/collections/collection2name/albums/album1name/photos/photo1name

if the user is multiple collections deep.

It's how to keep adding the levels of collections I am stuck with.

Any ideas how I can work with what I have to create URL's like that?

Comment: You're going to have a bad time if a gallery has a collection and an album with the exact same name. I would really consider name spacing the collections and albums. ex: `/gallery/c-cats/c-kittens/a-cute/123-photo`. That being said, to answer your question, you're going have to have generic routes, to a controller, which splits the URL string and figures out if each 'name' is a collection, album, or a photo.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my question wrong. Just going to reword it.  Hang on 1 minute.

Comment: Updated. Please could you ahve a look again?

Answer (score 0):

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

You have to cover zero deep paths

```
resources :photos
resources :albums
resources :collections
```

Now to cover infinite deepness

```
get '/gallery/*path/photos/:photo' => 'Photos#show'
get '/gallery/*path/albums/:album' => 'Albums#show'
get '/gallery/*path/collections/:collection' => 'Collections#show'
```

Comment: Will that allow a url like /gallery/photos/photo1  ?  If so then I don't want that.    I'm really confused with what the above is doing

Comment: I sort of get it. I'll have a play around and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I have managed to get it working for urls like /collections/591/albums/287  That works. I'm unsure how to create url paths in my views for when collections are inside other collections. Also, how do a put the whole lot so it shows up under /gallery/collections rather than just /collections   ?   Thanks so far!